Battery monitoring for voltage, current and capacity
I have a 12V 7Ah and 12V 18Ah lithium-ion battery at home. I want to be able to monitor the battery's voltage, current, and capacity.
I came across this IC from TI, BQ26621, however I then noticed this IC is not suited for 12V applications.

I then came across the BQ76972, however this IC is way overkill since I do not need the individual cell monitoring.
Does anyone know or advice what I can use to accomplish my objective?
